# How to use @extend for class that using numbers? (Migrating from bootstrap 4 to 5)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-5

i want to do migration for some classes from bootstrap 4 to 5,, because some of bootstrap classes is no longer can be used, such on utilities,, i'm using SASS so i can use @extend

[image]

for class .text-left and .text-right, i can easily @extend them

```
.text-left {
  @extend .text-start;
}

.text-right {
  @extend .text-end;
}
```

but for class (.ml- and .mr-) or (.pl- and .pr-) i have no idea how to do that without inserting them one bye one such .ml-1, .ml-2, etc.. Is there any idea how to put them only using one @extend instead of multiple @extend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, i use looping @for as written on this guide
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .ml-#{$i} {
    @extend .ms-#{$i};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BS5 API to change utilities class names:

```scss
$utilities: (
  "margin-end": (
    responsive: true,
    property: margin-right,
    // BS5 me-* classes become mr-*
    class: mr,
    values: map-merge($spacers, (auto: auto))
  ),
  "margin-start": (
    responsive: true,
    property: margin-left,
    // BS5 ms-* classes become ml-*
    class: ml,
    values: map-merge($spacers, (auto: auto))
  ),
  // ...other utilities
);
```

Place custom $utilities above importing BS5 utilities file (@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities") to update this utilities;

In this case you don't have to extend new BS5 classes in your code.